# How to use OrderBy in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-order-by

I have a table named `Person` with two columns: (PersonId - key, `PersonName`)

I'm trying to retrieve all persons ordered by `PersonName`.

The following code does NOT order my result:

```
var persons = from p in MyContext.Persons.OrderBy(x=>x.PersonName) select p;

var res = persons.Distnct().ToArray();
```

Is it possible to perform the order in that stage (I know that moving the `OrderBy` to the second row - after the evaluation - do the order)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq documentation says:

> The Distinct(...) method returns an **unordered** sequence that contains no duplicate values.

So order is not guaranteed to stay the same.
If you need guaranteed ordering after `.Distinct()` then your only option is to apply `.OrderBy()` again.

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can include both order by and distinct in a single query. Its working fine for me:

```
var persons = MyContext.Persons.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.Name).Distinct();
```

If you want to convert it to an array then use  ToArray() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = (from p in MyContext.Persons
                     select new
                     {
                         p.PersonName
                     }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.PersonName).ToArray();
```

Solution without `LINQ`

```
 var result = MyContext.Persons.Select(a => new { a.name }).Distinct().OrderBy(a => a.name).ToArray();
```

Comment: Your `Distinct` will destroy the order of `OrderBy`. You should reverse their order.